# When I run the following code the error " TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" shows

Tags: python, typeerror

Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c3w62.py", line 24, in <module>
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Code:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.parse as up
import json

serviceurl = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?"

while True:

    address = input("Enter location: ")

    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + up.urlencode({'sensor':'false','address':address})

    print ('Retrieving',url)

    uh =ur.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print ('Retrived',len(data),'characters')

    try: js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
        print (data)
        continue

    placeid = js["results"][0]['place_id']
    print ("Place id",placeid)
```

Comment: You must check if `js` is not `None` before attempting `if 'status' not in js`. For example, move the comparison into the body of the exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

As someone said,

```py
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.parse as up
import json

serviceurl = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?"

while True:

    address = input("Enter location: ")

    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + up.urlencode({'sensor':'false','address':address})

    print ('Retrieving',url)

    uh =ur.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print ('Retrived',len(data),'characters')

    try: js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: js = None

    if not js or 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK': # Changed this line
        print ('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
        print (data)
        continue

    placeid = js["results"][0]['place_id']
    print ("Place id",placeid)
```

Comment: I just changed url to " http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?" then it shows "Enter location: Madras university
Retrieving http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?sensor=false&address=Madras+university
Retrived 67 characters
==== Failure To Retrieve ====
b'Missing/incorrect key= parameter (it is an easy number to guess)...'
Enter location: Retrived 67 characters
==== Failure To Retrieve ====
b'Missing/incorrect key= parameter (it is an easy number to guess)...'
Enter location: 
"

Comment: Probably, your URI needs `key=...` param.